# Android Studio's Emulator not starting

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-8.1

I've recently installed Android Studio on Windows 8.1 and the emulator won't start when I try to run apps.

I have found the following error when I am trying to run the following error occurs

> 575-575/? I/PGA﹕ Attempting to create new SOCKET connectionn pid = 575, tid = 575

Comment: Try to Re-installation